# Prestashop Google Ecommerce Tracking

Tags: prestashop

I want to add Google Ecommerce Tracking to a Prestashop store. This should be done by adding the script to the 'order confirmation' pages.

However, the order data has been cleared by the time the 'order confirmation' page is displayed and therefore is not available to add to the GA script.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I use the Google Analytics built in module in Prestashop and turn on e-commerce tracking in GA. Works for me.

Comment: Please explain your answer better. If you just wanted to leave a comment, please wait until your score/reputation is higher. Enjoy SO!

Comment: This isn't the answer, as it will not capture any ecommerce data